# How to wait for Firebase data to be fetched before progressing?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, promise, fetch-api

I am fetching data from Fire store in real-time with .onSnapshot and it works great, I am receiving the data as expected. The problem is that I am receiving multiple sets of data, and the component does not wait until all the data is received before rendering.

So my question is, with my current code, is their a way in which I can wait for all sets of my data to be fetched before displaying them?

My current code is:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import FolloweringScreens from './FolloweringScreens';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('screen');

function Following({urlname, navigation}) {
  const [followingData, setfollowingData] = useState([]);

  // Follower counts, displayname, image
  const fetchData = () => {
    const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames');

    dataRef
      .doc(urlname)
      .collection('Following')
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          dataRef.doc(doc.id.toLowerCase()).onSnapshot((followerDoc) => {
            const data = followerDoc.data();
            setfollowingData((prev) => [
              ...prev,
              {
                profileName: doc.id,
                displayName: data.userName,
                followerCount:
                  data.followers !== undefined ? data.followers : 0,
                followingCount:
                  data.following !== undefined ? data.following : 0,
                image: data.imageUrl ? data.imageUrl : null,
              },
            ]);
          });
        });
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          left: width * 0.04,
          top: 50,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          width: '80%',
          height: '4%',
          marginBottom: 5,
        }}>
        {/* {console.log('followin', followingData)} */}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" color="#222" size={30} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{left: width * 0.05}}>Following</Text>
      </View>

      {followingData === [] ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <FolloweringScreens data={followingData} />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Following;
```

Comment: use loading state, initial false, then set true on snapshot, don't show ui until it's loaded. Don't use `onSnapshot` if you want to get the data once just use `get`

Comment: I want the display to change whenever the data is changed, so I need to use onSnapshot. Or is their a way to use get() and update the component whenever the data changes? Because when I use get(), i can wait for all the data to be fetched with a promise, but then when the data changes, you would have to manually refresh for the changes to be displayed.

Comment: Then just stick with onSnapshot, use a state `isLoading` default false, then set isLoading to true once a snapshot resolves, and show a loading indicator on isLoading true and show your ui when isLoading false. Then you get updates pushed to your state and the user will see the data once it's fully loaded

Comment: When dong this, the loader is displayed, and once the first set of data is fetched, the UI gets loaded, and the other sets of data get displayed one after the other, instead of all the data getting fetched, then the UI displaying. Where should I trigger the setloading? It seems like the state change triggers immediately after the first set of data is fetched unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to fix it somehow. Thanks to Julian for the help

What I did was create an array of promises which will be executed whenever the data changes. The code is:

```
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import FolloweringScreens from './FolloweringScreens';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('screen');

function Following({urlname, navigation}) {
  const [followingData, setfollowingData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // Following counts, displayname, image
  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames');

    dataRef
      .doc(urlname)
      .collection('Following')
      .limit(25)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const promise = dataRef
            .doc(doc.id.toLowerCase())
            .get()
            .then((followerDoc) => {
              const data = followerDoc.data();

              return {
                profileName: doc.id,
                displayName: data.displayName
                  ? data.displayName
                  : data.userName,
                followerCount:
                  data.followers !== undefined ? data.followers : 0,
                followingCount:
                  data.following !== undefined ? data.following : 0,
                image: data.imageUrl ? data.imageUrl : null,
              };
            });
          promises.push(promise);
        });
        Promise.all(promises)
          .then((res) => setfollowingData(res))
          .then(setLoading(false));
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
  const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames');

    const cleanup = dataRef
      .doc(urlname)
      .collection('Following')
      .limit(25)
      .onSnapshot(fetchData);

    return cleanup;

    // fetchData();
  }, [urlname, fetchData]);

  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={styles}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" color="#222" size={30} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{left: width * 0.05}}>Following</Text>
          </View>

      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <FolloweringScreens data={followingData} />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Following;
```

Comment: Okay, waaah :D some things really wrong here. For starters get used to async/await, it just creates a cleaner code. Dont use forEach to fill an array with promises, just use map and return the promises. Do not define the fetchData function outside your useEffect hook, it is missing a dependency. Check out my solution, where the function declaration is inside a useCallback hook

Comment: As well as I have to point out that this is not optimal. `dataRef` is a collection? So when you get a collection you can iterate over the documents in your collection with forEach, each `QueryDocumentSnapshot` has a `ref` prop which returns a `DocumentReference`, which you could use to reference the document or like in your case you want to get the data just get it with `snapshot.data()`, please refer to https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html

Comment: I would also store a `DocumentReference` to the document in your `usernames` collection within your document in `Following` collection

Comment: Then you get the data from your snapshot, or only the property that interests you (saves bandwidth and reduces costs) which is a reference and you can create the promises by running get on this reference

Comment: I have a lot to learn yet, but I am following what you are saying to some degree and so I have edited the answer and my code. With the promises, It doesn't let me map the snapshots, I can only use forEach, not sure why. Also, with the document reference, do you mean I should create a document reference within my following collection that points to the usernames collection? I did not know you could do this, that would be great if it is. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You're welcome, just keep it going. You can save a `DocumentReference` to a property in a `Document`, when you get this property you can get a snapshot directly and you wouldn't have to recreate the reference

Comment: So I was searching online, and now I am split on whether to create a document reference or duplicate the data. What would you recommend?

Comment: Create a reference, duplication of data is not so nice and suspect to data inconsistency, but if you do it right with firestore hooks than it could reduce the amount of read requests.

Answer (score 4):

Use a state isLoading default true, then set isLoading to false once a snapshot resolves, and show a loading indicator on isLoading true and show your ui when isLoading false. Then you get updates pushed to your state and the user will see the data once it's fully loaded.

Would also use something close to this. One thing that is quite weird is that you push every snapshot change to an array, so in other words over time this array holds a history of changes of the same object. Intentional?

```js
function Following({ urlname }) {
  const [followingData, setfollowingData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  // Follower counts, displayname, image
  const onSnapshot = useCallback((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      dataRef.doc(doc.id.toLowerCase()).onSnapshot((followerDoc) => {
        const data = followerDoc.data();
        // push new document data into an array
        setfollowingData((prev) => [
          ...prev,
          {
            profileName: doc.id,
            displayName: data.userName,
            followerCount: data.followers !== undefined ? data.followers : 0,
            followingCount: data.following !== undefined ? data.following : 0,
            image: data.imageUrl ? data.imageUrl : null
          }
        ]);
        // or set the new data to state, by just setting the document data
        setfollowingData(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataRef = firestore().collection("usernames");

    const cleanup = dataRef
      .doc(urlname)
      .collection("Following")
      .onSnapshot(onSnapshot);

    return cleanup;
  }, [onSnapshot, urlname]);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && <p>Loading</p>}
      {!isLoading && <p>Show data {followingData.length}</p>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: So this fixes everything, but what you said after, where every snapshot change is pushed to an array, therefore holding a history of changes is not intentional, this in fact makes it so that whenever a change is made, duplicate data is created. How could I make it so that the object updates when a change is made? instead of the data being added to the array? Thank you so much

Comment: I edited my answer and put two examples, one to push new document data to an array (existing) and how to set the new data to state, so that you would update your ui automatically if the data in the firestore changes

Comment: So I am pushing my data in to a Flat List, and I think it therefore needs to be in an array. But the first option poses the same problem, where whenever changes are made, a new set of data is added, instead of replaced.

Comment: How could you get a flat list from a firestore document? Do you want to get a collection maybe?