# Firebase only fetches data on second or third attempt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app with React and Firestore.

In one feature, I need to use some specific user data to query data from another collection, and show that on the app.

Specifically I want to use users.books, which returns an array, to query the collection books.

However, for some reason the users.books doesn't load on first render. It typically takes 2-3 renders to fetch the books.user data. This is despite the currentUserUID being loaded right away.

I've tried using a loading state as specified in [How to wait for Firebase data to be fetched before progressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831237/how-to-wait-for-firebase-data-to-be-fetched-before-progressing), but to no avail.

Do I need to use the onSnapShot method?

Thanks for reading

My code

```
import 'firebase/firestore'

import { booksRef} from '../../App';

const ProfileScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const currentUserUID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [userBookTitles, setUserBookTitles] = useState([]);
  const [userBooks, setUserBooks] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserInfo(){
      let doc = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(currentUserUID)
      .get();
      
      if (!doc.exists){
        Alert.alert('No user data found!')
      } else {
        let dataObj = doc.data();
        setFirstName(dataObj.firstName)
        setUserBookTitles(dataObj.books)
        console.log(userBookTitles)
      }
    }
    getUserInfo();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserBooks() {
    booksRef.where("title", "in", userBookTitles).onSnapshot(snapshot => (
    setUserBooks(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()})))
    ))
  }
  setLoading(false);
  getUserBooks()
  }, [])


      if (!loading) {
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text> Hi {firstName} </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
            
              <Text> Log out </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Row
                    books={userBooks}
            />
          </View>
      );  
    } else { 
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text> Test </Text>
        </View>
    );
    }
  };
```

Comment: I think you should call getUsersBooks function previous to the setLoading.

Comment: Made no difference unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's worth noting that your `setX` methods may, or may not, complete in the sequence you have them in your code. Therefore, your `booksRef` call could be being made even though `userBookTitles` is an empty array. Which would explain why you're not getting any data on load.

You're setting `userBookTitles` in your first `useEffect` and the only other place I see you're using it is in your `booksRef` call. One easy fix would be to simple move `booksRef` inside the `else` statement of the first `useEffect` and simply pass it the `userBookTitles` there. This should help in solving your issue, if I understood it correctly.